# How do I run a plist daemon on MAC OS 10.8.5 with the correct file permissions

Tags: macos, mac, permissions, python, plist

I have a plist file saved to

```
/Library/LaunchDaemons/local.WiFiDaemon.plist

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
        <key>Disabled</key>
        <false/>
        <key>GroupName</key>
        <string>staff</string>
        <key>InitGroups</key>
        <true/>
        <key>Label</key>
        <string>local.job</string>
        <key>ProgramArguments</key>
        <array>
                <string>python</string>
                <string>/Library/Application Support/PythonDaemons/PythonTest.py</string>
        </array>
        <key>RunAtLoad</key>
        <true/>
        <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
        <string>/tmp/local.job.err</string>
        <key>StandardOutPath</key>
        <string>/tmp/local.job.out</string>
        <key>UserName</key>
        <string>myuser</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

the file is supposed to execute a python script which just pings google and saves the results to a text file in:

```
/Library/Application Support/PythonDaemons/Ping_log.txt
```

the problem is the python script gives an error saying it doesn't have the permissions to the file.  When I run the script from the command line everything works fine without any special permissions needed.  What have I missed here?

Here's the python script:

```
import subprocess, datetime, time

host = "www.google.com"
ping = subprocess.Popen(
                        ["ping", "-c", "4", host],
                        stdout = subprocess.PIPE,
                        stderr = subprocess.PIPE)
out, error = ping.communicate()
with open('PingOut.txt', 'w') as outFile:
    outFile.write(out)
temp = out.split('\n')
parsed = temp[len(temp)-2].split('/')
min = parsed[len(parsed)-4].split(' ')[2]
avg = parsed[len(parsed)-3]
max = parsed[len(parsed)-2]

print "min: " + str(min) + "avg: " + str(avg) + "max: " + str(max)

with open('Ping_log.txt', 'a') as f:
 f.write(str(datetime.datetime.now()) + ',' + str(min) + ',' + str(avg) + ',' + str(max))
```

Comment: what are the access rights to ```/Library/Application Support/PythonDaemons/```?

Comment: I just changed the permissions to dwr-wr-wr- and is still give the error: `traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Application Support/PythonDaemons/PythonTest.py", line 15, in <module>
    with open('PingOut.txt', 'w') as outFile:
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'PingOut.txt'`

Comment: As it is a folder it needs drwxrwxrwx. Otherwise no one is allowed to move into the folder and therefore can't create a file.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer via stackoverflow, apparently without defining the path in the python file and just providing the file names it defaults to creating the files in a system directory that I don't have access to.  The solutions are:
set the working path in python

```
with open('/Library/Application Support/PythonDaemons/Ping_log.txt', 'a') as f:
```

or set the directory in the plist

```
<key>WorkingDirectory</key>
<string>/Library/Application Support/PythonDaemons</string>
```

This was provided by user Barmar at StackOverflow